# How to back propagate a Neural Network in C++?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I have been trying to make a neural network in c++ and my back propagation code is not working the way I want it to. I have a text document that tells the network how to function. I have it have 2 input neurons, 1 hidden layer with 4 neurons and 2 output neurons. I have it learning to be an XOR gate right now. I have it so it takes the cost of the network, multiplys it by .55(scaling) and adding/subtracting that from the weights/bias' depending on how close the output is from the correct answer and weither or not the weights/bias' are + or -. Here's the code:

```
void Network::backProp(void)
{
double b = 0,a;
int loop,l;


for(loop=0;loop<4;loop++)
{
    //Adds up the cost of the data
    b = b + (pow(results[2*loop]-key[4*loop+2],2)+pow(results[2*loop+1]-key[4*loop+3],2));
}
a=.55*b;
if(b>.01)
{
for(l=0;l<4;l++)
{
    if(round(results[2*l])!=key[4*l+2])
    {
        if(data[0] <= 0)
        {
            data[0] = data[0]+a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[0] = data[0]-a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        if(data[1] <= 0)
        {
            data[1] = data[1]+a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[1] = data[1]-a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        if(data[2] <= 0)
        {
            data[2] = data[2]+a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[2] = data[2]-a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        if(data[3] <= 0)
        {
            data[3] = data[3]+a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[3] = data[3]-a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        if(data[4] <= 0)
        {
            data[4] = data[4]+a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[4] = data[4]-a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        if(data[6] <= 0)
        {
            data[6] = data[6]+a; //(abs(data[6])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[6] = data[6]-a; //(abs(data[6])/a);
        }
        if(data[7] <= 0)
        {
            data[7] = data[7]+a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[7] = data[7]-a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        if(data[8] <= 0)
        {
            data[8] = data[8]+a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[8] = data[8]-a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        if(data[9] <= 0)
        {
            data[9] = data[9]+a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[9] = data[9]-a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        if(data[10] <= 0)
        {
            data[10] = data[10]+a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[10] = data[10]-a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        if(data[11] <= 0)
        {
            data[11] = data[11]+a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[11] = data[11]-a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        if(data[12] <= 0)
        {
            data[12] = data[12]+a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[12] = data[12]-a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        if(data[13] <= 0)
        {
            data[13] = data[13]+a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[13] = data[13]-a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        if(data[14] <= 0)
        {
            data[14] = data[14]+a; //(abs(data[14])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[14] = data[14]-a; //(abs(data[14])/a);
        }
        if(data[16] <= 0)
        {
            data[16] = data[16]+a; //(abs(data[16])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[16] = data[16]-a; //(abs(data[16])/a);
        }
        if(data[18] <= 0)
        {
            data[18] = data[18]+a; //(abs(data[18])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[18] = data[18]-a; //(abs(data[18])/a);
        }
        if(data[20] <= 0)
        {
            data[20] = data[20]+a; //(abs(data[20])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[20] = data[20]-a; //(abs(data[20])/a);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(data[0] <= 0)
        {
            data[0] = data[0]-a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[0] = data[0]+a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        if(data[1] <= 0)
        {
            data[1] = data[1]-a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[1] = data[1]+a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
       if(data[2] <= 0)
       {
            data[2] = data[2]-a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
       }
        else
        {
            data[2] = data[2]+a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        if(data[3] <= 0)
        {
            data[3] = data[3]-a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[3] = data[3]+a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        if(data[4] <= 0)
        {
            data[4] = data[4]-a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[4] = data[4]+a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        if(data[6] <= 0)
        {
            data[6] = data[6]-a; //(abs(data[6])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[6] = data[6]+a; //(abs(data[6])/a);
        }
        if(data[7] <= 0)
        {
            data[7] = data[7]-a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[7] = data[7]+a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        if(data[8] <= 0)
        {
            data[8] = data[8]-a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[8] = data[8]+a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        if(data[9] <= 0)
        {
            data[9] = data[9]-a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[9] = data[9]+a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        if(data[10] <= 0)
        {
            data[10] = data[10]-a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[10] = data[10]+a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        if(data[11] <= 0)
        {
            data[11] = data[11]-a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[11] = data[11]+a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        if(data[12] <= 0)
        {
            data[12] = data[12]-a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[12] = data[12]+a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        if(data[13] <= 0)
        {
            data[13] = data[13]-a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[13] = data[13]+a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        if(data[14] <= 0)
        {
            data[14] = data[14]-a; //(abs(data[14])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[14] = data[14]+a; //(abs(data[14])/a);
        }
        if(data[16] <= 0)
        {
            data[16] = data[16]-a; //(abs(data[16])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[16] = data[16]+a; //(abs(data[16])/a);
        }
        if(data[18] <= 0)
        {
            data[18] = data[18]-a; //(abs(data[18])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[18] = data[18]+a; //(abs(data[18])/a);
        }
        if(data[20] <= 0)
        {
            data[20] = data[20]-a; //(abs(data[20])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[20] = data[20]+a; //(abs(data[20])/a);
        }
    }
    if(round(results[2*l+1])!=key[4*l+3])
    {
        if(data[0] <= 0)
        {
            data[0] = data[0]+a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[0] = data[0]-a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        if(data[1] <= 0)
        {
            data[1] = data[1]+a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[1] = data[1]-a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        if(data[2] <= 0)
        {
            data[2] = data[2]+a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[2] = data[2]-a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        if(data[3] <= 0)
        {
            data[3] = data[3]+a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[3] = data[3]-a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        if(data[4] <= 0)
        {
            data[4] = data[4]+a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[4] = data[4]-a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        if(data[5] <= 0)
        {
            data[5] = data[5]+a; //(abs(data[5])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[5] = data[5]-a; //(abs(data[5])/a);
        }
        if(data[7] <= 0)
        {
            data[7] = data[7]+a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[7] = data[7]-a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        if(data[8] <= 0)
        {
            data[8] = data[8]+a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[8] = data[8]-a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        if(data[9] <= 0)
        {
            data[9] = data[9]+a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[9] = data[9]-a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        if(data[10] <= 0)
        {
            data[10] = data[10]+a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[10] = data[10]-a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        if(data[11] <= 0)
        {
            data[11] = data[11]+a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[11] = data[11]-a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        if(data[12] <= 0)
        {
            data[12] = data[12]+a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[12] = data[12]-a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        if(data[13] <= 0)
        {
            data[13] = data[13]+a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[13] = data[13]-a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        if(data[15] <= 0)
        {
            data[15] = data[15]+a; //(abs(data[15])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[15] = data[15]-a; //(abs(data[15])/a);
        }
        if(data[17] <= 0)
        {
            data[17] = data[17]+a; //(abs(data[17])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[17] = data[17]-a; //(abs(data[17])/a);
        }
        if(data[19] <= 0)
        {
            data[19] = data[19]+a; //(abs(data[19])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[19] = data[19]-a; //(abs(data[19])/a);
        }
        if(data[21] <= 0)
        {
            data[21] = data[21]+a; //(abs(data[21])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[21] = data[21]-a; //(abs(data[21])/a);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(data[0] <= 0)
        {
            data[0] = data[0]-a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[0] = data[0]+a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
        }
        if(data[1] <= 0)
        {
            data[1] = data[1]-a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[1] = data[1]+a; //(abs(data[1])/a);
        }
       if(data[2] <= 0)
       {
            data[2] = data[2]-a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
       }
        else
        {
            data[2] = data[2]+a; //(abs(data[2])/a);
        }
        if(data[3] <= 0)
        {
            data[3] = data[3]-a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[3] = data[3]+a; //(abs(data[3])/a);
        }
        if(data[4] <= 0)
        {
            data[4] = data[4]-a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[4] = data[4]+a; //(abs(data[4])/a);
        }
        if(data[5] <= 0)
        {
            data[5] = data[5]-a; //(abs(data[5])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[5] = data[5]+a; //(abs(data[5])/a);
        }
        if(data[7] <= 0)
        {
            data[7] = data[7]-a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[7] = data[7]+a; //(abs(data[7])/a);
        }
        if(data[8] <= 0)
        {
            data[8] = data[8]-a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[8] = data[8]+a; //(abs(data[8])/a);
        }
        if(data[9] <= 0)
        {
            data[9] = data[9]-a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[9] = data[9]+a; //(abs(data[9])/a);
        }
        if(data[10] <= 0)
        {
            data[10] = data[10]-a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[10] = data[10]+a; //(abs(data[10])/a);
        }
        if(data[11] <= 0)
        {
            data[11] = data[11]-a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[11] = data[11]+a; //(abs(data[11])/a);
        }
        if(data[12] <= 0)
        {
            data[12] = data[12]-a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[12] = data[12]+a; //(abs(data[12])/a);
        }
        if(data[13] <= 0)
        {
            data[13] = data[13]-a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[13] = data[13]+a; //(abs(data[13])/a);
        }
        if(data[15] <= 0)
        {
            data[15] = data[15]-a; //(abs(data[15])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[15] = data[15]+a; //(abs(data[15])/a);
        }
        if(data[17] <= 0)
        {
            data[17] = data[17]-a; //(abs(data[17])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[17] = data[17]+a; //(abs(data[17])/a);
        }
        if(data[19] <= 0)
        {
            data[19] = data[19]-a; //(abs(data[19])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[19] = data[19]+a; //(abs(data[19])/a);
        }
        if(data[21] <= 0)
        {
            data[21] = data[21]-a; //(abs(data[21])/a);
        }
        else
        {
            data[21] = data[21]+a; //(abs(data[21])/a);
        }
    }
 }
 }
}
```

I know it's a mess but this is what I came up with. I can post the rest of the code if that would help.

Comment: I think you have a copy+paste typo regarding `data[5]` that wouldn't have happened if you had written a loop instead of pasting the same code over and over.  Should `data[17]` be missing?  Should `data[19]` be missing?

Comment: I tried doing a loop, but I have tried it and it won't work because for the first big if statement, I don't use data[5,15,17,19,21] and for the second big if I don't use data[6,14,16,18,20]

Comment: @MSalters the OP's question is about back propagation in NN, there is nothing wrong with nearly identical if statements especially since they are not ALL used in all conditions as pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code

```
void Network::backProp(void)
{
    double b = 0,a;
    int loop,l;
    int inclusion1 [] = {0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,20};
    int inclusion2 [] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,17,19,21};
    int j = 0;
    for(loop=0;loop<4;loop++)
    {
    //Adds up the cost of the data
        b = b + (pow(results[2*loop]-key[4*loop+2],2)+pow(results[2*loop+1]-key[4*loop+3],2));
    }
    a=.55*b;

    if(b>.01)
    {
        for(l=0;l<4;l++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<17;j++)
            {
                if(round(results[2*l])!=key[4*l+2])
                {
                    data[inclusion1[j]] = data[inclusion1[j]] - abs(data[inclusion1[j]])/data[inclusion1[j]]*a;
                }

                if(round(results[2*l+1])!=key[4*l+3])
                {
                    data[inclusion2[j]] = data[inclusion2[j]] + abs(data[inclusion2[j]])/data[inclusion2[j]]*a;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic issue as I see is it that your correction variable b i dont think it is defined accurately

Should be more along the lines

```
b = b + pow((pow(results[2*loop]-key[4*loop+2],2)+pow(results[2*loop+1]-key[4*loop+3],2)),1/2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot. I forgot to sqrt the cost value and that helped a lot. Also, you shortened my code by a good 600 lines and I thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

move this block to seperate function:

```
    if(data[0] <= 0)
    {
        data[0] = data[0]+a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
    }
    else
    {
        data[0] = data[0]-a; //(abs(data[0])/a);
    }
```

like this: (find proper name)

```
void AddAtoData(int& data, a)
{
    if(data <= 0)
    {
        data += a;
    }
    else
    {
        data -= a;
    }
}
```

then split your data[] structure to logical units, e.g. your layers to avoid the other if-logic and use loops.

once you cleaned up, look if your problem still exists, if so, come back.